# How to Append Acumatica DAC attribute [PXEmailSource]

Tags: acumatica

I want to know the best way to append the DAC attributes..Please note I need Appending method for DAC Attributes not DAC Field Attributes.
Specifically I need to append [PXEMailSource] to some of the existing DACs
Eg: PX.Objects.IN.INRegister
What is the best way to do it ...?
Any helps regarding this will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the attribute of the DAC using `PXSubstituteAttribute`

Note from **Acumatica Framework Development Guide**(page 95)

> **PXSubstitute Attribute**
>   Indicates that the derived DAC should replace its base DACs in a specific graph or all graphs.
>
> **• public Type GraphType**
>   Gets or sets the specific graph in which the derived DAC replaces base DACs.
>   **• public Type ParentType**
>   Gets or sets the base DAC type up to which all types in the inheritance
>   hierarchy are substituted with the derived DAC. By default, the property
>   has the null value, which means that all base DACs are substituted with the
>   derived DAC
>
> **Remarks**
>   The attribute is placed on the definition of a DAC that is
>   derived from another DAC. The attribute is used primarily to make the
>   declarative references of the base DAC in definitions of calculations
>   and links from child objects to parent objects be interpreted as the
>   references of the derived DAC.

Below is the example how to use `Attribute` on `INRegister` DAC.

```
[PXPrimaryGraph(new Type[]
{
    typeof(INReceiptEntry),
    typeof(INIssueEntry),
    typeof(INTransferEntry),
    typeof(INAdjustmentEntry),
    typeof(KitAssemblyEntry),
    typeof(KitAssemblyEntry)
}, new Type[]
{
    typeof(Where<INRegister.docType, Equal<INDocType.receipt>>),
    typeof(Where<INRegister.docType, Equal<INDocType.issue>>),
    typeof(Where<INRegister.docType, Equal<INDocType.transfer>>),
    typeof(Where<INRegister.docType, Equal<INDocType.adjustment>>),
    typeof(Select<INKitRegister, Where<INKitRegister.docType, Equal<INDocType.production>, And<INKitRegister.refNbr, Equal<Current<INRegister.refNbr>>>>>),
    typeof(Select<INKitRegister, Where<INKitRegister.docType, Equal<INDocType.disassembly>, And<INKitRegister.refNbr, Equal<Current<INRegister.refNbr>>>>>)
})]
[INRegisterCacheName("Receipt")]
[Serializable]
[PXSubstitute(GraphType = typeof(REQUIREDGRAPH_WHERE_SHOULD_BE_SUBSTITED))]
[PXEMailSource]          
public class INRegisterExt: INRegister   
{ 
  //...    
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer Samvel,Unfortunately this customization also not solving my issue anyhow this should be the proper way to append the DAC attributes.
Thanks again